# Html 5 web page with video and overlay

Tags: iphone, html5-video

I'm trying to create a web page, with an html 5 video that has some other elements over it (divs, with text etc) that appear at certain times.  My understanding is that on the iphone, you cannot have these videos in the page itself but that they instead pop open in a new windows (quicktime?)  However, can i still have html 5 elements absolutely positioned and displayed over the video while its playing, or does the mobile version of quicktime not allow that?

Thanks,
Craig